# C# class from library not found or does not exist

Tags: c#, lib

I have a C# WinForms program and I created also a C# library. I added in the main project a reference to the library project. Oversimplifying, the code looks like following:

The Library:

```
namespace nsDiscovery
{
    public class Foo1 { }
    public class ClassDiscovery
    {
        public class Foo2 { }
...
```

The Program:

```
using nsDiscovery;
namespace nsMDNS
{
    public partial class Form_MDNS : Form
    {
        private void TstFooA( Foo1[] f1_, ClassDiscovery.Foo2[] f2_ ){}
        private void TstFooB()
        {
            Foo1[] f1 = new Foo1[ 0 ];
            ClassDiscovery.Foo2[] f2 = new ClassDiscovery.Foo2[ 0 ];
        }
...
```

The function TstFooB() has no problems but function TstFooA() triggers at compile time two errors:

- The type or namespace name 'Foo1' could not be found;
- The type name 'Foo2' does not exist in the type 'nsDiscovery.ClassDiscovery

The even more annoying thing is that I have also created a separate dummy solution just to experiment all the above and there it works. So in the real project(s) I must have done something wrong but I can't figure out what. It's true that the real project and the real library are actually much more complex.

Comment: Is the library placed in the same directory than the .exe from the forms project? Do they have the same target architecture, .Net versions, etc?

Comment: Try `global::nsDiscovery.Foo1` for `Foo1` and `global::nsDiscovery.ClassDiscovery.Foo2` for `Foo2`. If not work, it maybe caused by referencing assemblies.

Comment: Are you sure you're referring to the classes in *exactly* the same way in `TstFooA` and `TstFooB`, and that they're in the same source file, within the same namespace declaration? (As an aside, do your namespaces actually start with `ns`? If so, I'd strongly recommend that you start following .NET naming conventions. If not, I'd advise you to start following the normal naming conventions in questions, to avoid distractions.)

Comment: Are there any other compilation errors? Could be as simple as the referenced project didn't compile.

Comment: @John Wu You were right, the lib had some errors and didn't compile; after that it worked